# Use dplyr to save existing variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with Month, Week, Total Amount, etc. I tried to create a new dataset with two new variables, Total Amount by Week and Average Amount by Week.

```
order_sum <- allorders %>% 
  select(Month,Week,Total) %>%
  group_by(Week) %>% summarize(Avg_Amount   = mean(Total), 
                               Total_Amount = sum(Total))
```

I get the new dataset, but this new dataset didn't have the Month variable.

How do I keep it?

The sample dataset is:

```
Month Week Total
01    01    1
01    02    2
01    02    2
01    03    1
01    03    2
02    05    1
02    06    1
02    06    1
```

I need to get the dataset:

```
Month Week Avg_Total_by_week Total_by_week
.....
```

Comment: you may want to add it to `group_by(Month, Week)`

Comment: use group_by(Month,Week) ,so it will keep Month variable, and group by ONLY week variable?

Comment: no it would group on the interaction of month and week, so each unique week in each unique month. If you are trying to look at a monthly pattern/cycle then grouping by week only would make sense, but in that case it wouldn't make sense to try and bring month back in

Comment: Just use `mutate` instead of `summarize` it work's the same but keeps all columns

Comment: @wici I tried mutute,but I don't want to keep total variable,can I delete it?

Comment: Just drop it after `mutate` with `select(-Total)`

Answer (score 1):

Just do this!

```
order_sum <- allorders %>% 
select(Month,Week,Total) %>%
group_by(Month, Week) %>% summarize(Avg_Amount=mean(Total), 
                         Total_Amount=sum(Total))
```

or if you want to keep original data:

```
order_sum <- allorders %>% 
select(Month,Week,Total) %>%
group_by(Month, Week) %>% 
mutate(Avg_Amount=mean(Total), 
       Total_Amount=sum(Total))
```

Comment: I only want to group by week,and keep month variable.How can we edit it?

Comment: the unique combinations of week and month are the same as the unique weeks, so you can just group by both. If you are looking to group by just week (all first weeks, all second weeks, and so on, then you should not need the months because that is what you are trying to aggregate out. If you want to keep that, use `mutate()` in place of `summarize()`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to group by Month, then by Week, and then summarize, just ask summarize to show the Month column.

```
order_sum <- allorders %>% 
  select(Month,Week,Total) %>%
  group_by(Week) %>% summarize(Month,
                               Avg_Amount   = mean(Total), 
                               Total_Amount = sum(Total))
```

Comment: I tried this method,there is an error: Error: expecting a single value. Do you know why?

Comment: This would work if you have only one pairing of Month and Week.
That is, Week 1 appears only once, in a specific Month, and doesn't appear in any other month.
If this is not the case, then `summarize` doesn't know what Month to return and an Error occurs.